# How to get the subscriber count of a YouTube channel to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a list of YouTube channels' URLs. How do I get their subscriber count to a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube Data API v3 credentials will be required. See:

- [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)
- [Obtaining Credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application)

Once you get the API key:

1. Get your URL list to a Google Sheet.
2. Create a new Google Apps Script project. (Tools > Script Editor)
3. Paste this code to your script file:

   ```
    var api_key='YOUR_API_KEY'
    var google_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels/' 
    var url_id = google_url + '?key=' + api_key + '&part=statistics' + '&id='

    function GET_SUBS(input) {
        /** Takes channel ID as input and returns the subscriber count */
        url_id = url_id + input
        return +ImportJSON(url_id, "/items/statistics/subscriberCount", "noHeaders")
    }
   ```
4. Click on the plus icon next to the "Files" and choose "Script". Rename your new script file as "ImportJSON" and [paste this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164/raw/047b04a1c321b697533adad5828e6df8748b5e54/import_json_appsscript.js).
5. Go back to the sheet and set up a column for channel IDs. You can use the following code to strip ID of a channel from the URL:

   ```
   =ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE('CHANNEL_URL',"(.*\/)(.*)$","$2"))
   ```

[image: Sample table.]

6. Use the GET_SUBS() function to get the follower count.

   ```
   GET_SUBS('CHANNEL_ID')
   ```

Note: Currently YouTube API doesn't provide the exact subscriber count of a channel publicly. [See this Stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65407944/how-to-get-exact-subscribers-count-from-a-youtube-channel) So the results we have are rounded.